# How to force `dotnet` CLI to return non zero exit code?

Tags: powershell, dotnet-cli

I run `dotnet` from powershell script, and when I specify some unknown switch powershell does not detect any error. And output goes to `stdout` whereas I'd expect it to be `stderr`.

Is it a setting on dotnet or powershell side? I need script to fail in case of errors.

> dotnet pack -dsfsdf Microsoft (R) Build Engine version
> 15.8.166+gd4e8d81a88 for .NET Core Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch. Switch: -dsfsdf
>
> For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed dotnet-pack writes errors to stdout, however it sets exit code to 1 in case of unknown parameter. You can check it with following code:

```
dotnet pack -asd
echo $LASTEXITCODE
```